# Knockoutjs arrayFilter multiple dropdowns

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a question regarding arrayFilter in knockoutjs, how would i go about filtering my list with 2 different dropdowns which whould be related so if i have choosen 1 type of building but no area i should be shown all of that type of buildings, however if i where to choose a building option and an area option the filtering should account for that, ive been working on a prototype now for 2 days but cant figure out how to return the correct item in the arrayfilter.

http://jsfiddle.net/vGg2h/138/

Currently i made all my models and pastin in data via the viewmodel, and i got a filtered list hooked up, however i dont understand how to return the correct item back through the foreach filter and the arrayFilter, this is where it gets abit blurry.

```
       self.filteredList = ko.computed(function () {
            var filters = [];
            filters.push(self.selectedBuilding());
            filters.push(self.selectedArea());
           var currentList = [];

            ko.utils.arrayForEach(filters, function (filter) {
                if (typeof filter !== "undefined") {
                 ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.products(), function (item) {
                    if (filter.id == item.areaId || filter.value == item.buildingId) {
                            currentList.push(item);
                        } 
                 });
                }

            });
            return currentList;
        });
```

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

- you are not correctly using `ko.utils.arrayFilter`: you have to return `true` or `false` depending on whether and item should be included in the end result or not. So you should not build your result inside the `arrayFilter`
- you are always starting form the full list and not applying the filters one after the other, but incorrectly build the result in the `arrayFilter` which lead to combining your filters with OR and not with AND as you originally wanted

Your fixed code would like this:

```
self.filteredList = ko.computed(function () {
    var filters = [];
    filters.push(self.selectedBuilding());
    filters.push(self.selectedArea());
    var currentList = self.products();

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(filters, function (filter) {
        if (typeof filter !== "undefined") {
            currentList = ko.utils.arrayFilter(currentList, function (item) {
                if (filter.id == item.areaId || filter.value == item.buildingId) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return currentList;
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nepbna1n/)

Two better see the **AND** filtering with reusing the same list you can rewrite your code to do the filtering in two separate steps:

```
self.filteredList = ko.computed(function () {
    var currentList = self.products();
    if (self.selectedBuilding())
    {
        currentList = ko.utils.arrayFilter(currentList, function(item) {
            return self.selectedBuilding().value == item.buildingId;
        });
    }
    if (self.selectedArea())
    {
        currentList = ko.utils.arrayFilter(currentList, function(item) {
            return self.selectedArea().id == item.areaId;
        });
    }
    return currentList;
});
```

In this code it is more clearer that you start from the full list and then apply the different filters one by one, further and further filtering the original list.

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bxL1e9wo/)

Note: if you initially want to start with an empty list (like in your original code) then you can just return an empty array if all of your filters are empty:

```
self.filteredList = ko.computed(function () {
    if (!self.selectedBuilding() && !self.selectedArea())
        return [];
    //...
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djczsnp3/).

Comment: Thank you so much!  Iv'e been looking into this for some time now and just couldnt get the filtering right, and i started the whole foreach filter and that made me very confused, this solution is clean readable and very nice.  i will mark this as the answer.

Comment: I ended up using the last option as this was alot more clean than my initial code, this was really helpful for me seeing how you could write this code more efficient, would it be possible to filter the dropdowns similarly so if there is no content in them simply dont show them in the list, i tried doing this in a fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/bxL1e9wo/1/ Appreciate your time taken!

Comment: @JakobKristensen it is highly recommended that if you have these kind of different, but follow up questions, you ask them as separate questions. It is hard to properly answer in the comments and other users may not notice and question buried in the comments. On the other hand your description is not very clear, I'm not sure how you've imagined the filtering of the dropdowns... are you looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/t8ep835u/?

Comment: This was the exact solution i was looking for, i will create a followup question next time, thanks for clarifying. My attempt looked abit different http://jsfiddle.net/bxL1e9wo/2/ i like your approach however, thank you so much for helping with these issues.